# What does it mean by an "instinct" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Was it about the government's instinct (feeling) that such wage restraint efforts could transform the country into an economic giant? Would someone help me to clarify this?

*Underlying Germany’s surplus is a decades-old accord between business and unions in favour of wage restraint to keep export industries competitive (see article). Such moderation served Germany’s export-led economy well through its postwar recovery and beyond. **It is an instinct that helps explain Germany’s transformation since the late 1990s from Europe’s sick man to today’s muscle-bound champion.***

*Why Germany's current-account surplus is bad for the world economy*, The Economist, July 8 2017 http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21724810-country-saves-too-much-and-spends-too-little-why-germanys-current-account-surplus-bad

Answer (score 2):

The word **instinct** in this context means this:

> the fact or quality of possessing innate behaviour patterns

This claim is bolstered by the words "...a decade-old tradition..." in the excerpt.

So the second and the third sentences can now be comprehended this way

> The moderation, which is an age-old behaviour of Germany, helps explain Germany’s transformation since the late 1990s from Europe’s sick man to today’s muscle-bound champion.

Comment: I'm glad it helped @Bakebake